# female connector

Tags: connector, uart

Does anyone have an idea of what type of connector this is? Looks like some type of molex, with 1.5mm pin spacing but I am having trouble with finding something that fits it.

[image]

Comment: Have you searched for JST connectors?

Comment: It really looks like JST PH connectors, but those are 2.0mm pitch, so it is strange. Can you double-check the pitch ? [See DigiKey entry for the part](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/jst-sales-america-inc/B4B-PH-K-S(LF)(SN)/455-1706-ND/926613)

Answer (score 1):

It is a JST B4B-ZR and you can get it [here](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/jst-sales-america-inc/B4B-ZR(LF)(SN)/455-1659-ND/926566).